# Error when configuring Python interpreter for PyDev in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, configuration, pydev, interpreter

I just recently installed the PyDev 2.6 plugin for Eclipse (I run Eclipse SDK 4.2.1) and when I try to configure the Python interpreter to the path: > C:\Python27\python.exe , it gives me an "Error info on interpreter" and in error log it says:

> com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: unvalid Byte 2 of the sequence UTF-8 of 3 bytes

I have read other similar questions on this website about the same issue but the solutions do not suit my situation, as I don't have any unicode char in my path. I run Python 2.7.3. I would really appreciate any help or advice on how to solve this issue, as I would really love to start coding Python in Eclipse soon. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced same problem. The solution was reinstalling Aptana (or Eclipse, tested also on Kepler 4.2.x).

The source of problem was in path to your eclipse/aptana installition. I think that trouble here is determined by diacritic symbols in your name 'Andres Diaz', according to your username here))) (my case is: cyrillic username and user's home folder 'Михаил' in Windows8). Path to your python interpreter does not matter here.

The cure is: move/reinstall your Eclipse to folder with the path which does not contain any non-acsii character. In my case I've moved Aptana Studio from C:\Users\Михаил\Aptana3 to C:\Aptana3 and (maybe it's not necesarry, I don't know) its' workspace also to root C:\ folder.

P.S. I think it can be useful for those who also faced such problem cause I was not able to find any answer about how to solve this troubles but a lot of similar questions.
P.P.S. Sorry for my English, languages are not my leading skill)))